# Machine learning libraries support to spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming

I am working on the spark streaming project where machine learning need to implemented.
I have seen there are couple of algorithms are present in spark but mostly for batch only.
For streaming, there are only streaming linear regression and kmeans streaming are present .
Is it true. Can I use other machine learning libraries ( random forest) in streaming ?

Comment: In spark-streaming when you need aggregation of previous data, you need to recompute the RDD. In those cases its not feasible to use streaming but in rest of the places you can use stream. In cases when you need aggregation, you have to follow a different approach.

Comment: random forest is impossible to train in online scenario in general - this is not about library, but the model itself. There are some modifications supporting it (like Mondraian Forests) but this is different algorithm